# Tapestry 5, Logging in the classes that are not pages

Tags: java, slf4j, tapestry

I'm using Mark W. Shead's 10 Minute Demo (the link is visible from [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/getting-started.html)) on Tomcat, and it works fine.  The direct link to the source code is [here](https://github.com/markshead/10min-tapestry5/)

I would like put some logging into the classes that are not page classes.  For example, the .services.AppModule class.

In the Tapestry documentation it has an example for a page class like this:

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;

public class MyPage
{
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    void onSuccessFromForm()
    {
        logger.info("Changes saved successfully");
    }
```

But I can't get that to work for the other classes, like AppModule.
I get a null pointer exception when I try to use the log.

I also tried this:

```
@Inject
public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppModule.class);
```

This runs but I get no messages.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: @Kohei TAMURA thanks for cleaning my question up.  I couldn't get it to work for me so I said "f-it, post the question anyway maybe someone will help.

Comment: Can you show us more details? e.g. What inject do you import spring or tapestry?

Comment: @LakiGeri I use Tapestry injection.  I added the link to the source code in the question (instead of the link to the link).  I have made no modifications to this code except what is in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppModule.class);
```

because of the injecting, I should not to initialise the logger, or you init the logger without inject

I think the problem is that logger is not defined in spring or somewhere, that's why the tapestry can not inject just a null reference. If you want to inject the logger, and not create it, you should find out, why dont the tapestry-project init the logger.

Comment: I like the "tapestry-project init the logger" idea.  Can you put some code or pseudo-code in your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: first question, have you made the log4j properties file?

Comment: Honestly I dont know what causes this problem.. I've never met a problem like this, I just give you an advice, what would i do

Comment: OK, that works.  Thanks!  But it's not a this-is-how-you-should-do-it in Tapestry answer.  I believe that the real answer involves making a logging service and binding it etc. so injection works.  But I don't know how to do that and I haven't been able to find anything cogent on the Tapestry site.

Comment: I agree with you, its not the best solution, but works..
and the Tapestry site.. its a piece of ... :) I really don't know why can not they do a normal useful site, as other frameworks have. I can recommend you this site for T5.3 & T5.4 http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/